# Firefox Portable: addons are marked as "not compatible"

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, portable-apps

I'm using Firefox Portable from portableapps.com, the program is stored in my Dropbox folder.

Everything works OK, except for a few addons, namely: LastPass and URL Alias. When I finished to work from one PC and move to another, on a first run of Firefox, they are turned off and marked as "not compatible with current version of Firefox". However, once I clicked "Search for addon updates" caption changes to "Addon will be enabled after you restart Firefox" and indeed, they starts to work OK after restart.

I've tried to use Hg to get a diff between these two states (after Firefox folder was updated by Dropbox, i.e. synced with another PC, and after I do that silly "Search for updates" and addons are turned back on), but there are just too much changes (and most of the files are binaries).

What I'm looking for:

1. Hints about how can I find what's happening with the Firefox during sync process.
2. Way to automate the process of searching for addon updates, either addon or some other way (I've already try [Addons update checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/addon-update-checker/#id=327783), but no luck, he doesn't fix "not compatible" addons by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure regarding the things you're looking for, but, a possible solution to the direct issue of addons being disabled and having to restart could potentially be editing the about:config and setting the 'extensions.checkCompatibility.22.0' to false (replace 22.0 w/ w/e version of ff you're running, can be found in Help > About Firefox), which should allow the plugins to run despite being marked as not compatible. An extension that could help with automating this if you get tired of doing it manually after each update is [NightlyTesterTools](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Auto-tools/Automation_Development/Projects/Addons/NightlyTesterTools).

So, to recap, this doesn't automate the process of searching for the updates, but, it does technically fix the issue of the addons not being started upon startup, so, this would be more of a temporary fix than a permanent one.